# Recover erased data

Tags: hard-drive, imac, macos, disk-utility

so I just did a fresh install of Sierra. Then it turned out the files are needed. I erased my drive with the fastest option and didn't installed anything on it yet except the os so I think most of the data should be recoverable. What's the best possible way to recover the erased data?

Comment: Marked as unclear (probably an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/272179)): If you are asking like that, I don't recommend to install and use testdisk without further instructions! Instead rewrite your question and tell us your real problem (i.e. what's the reason to install testdisk > e.g. partition/data recovery)

Comment: Lots of duplicates - it will really depend on your decision to pay for help or DIY and the specific details of your setup to know which duplicate best fits your scenario. Go ahead and edit the post with some specifics and we can point to a better dupe or perhaps reopen if you have a new situation that's not covered already.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88538/ and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237858/ and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234179/ and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164150/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is to stop using the computer right away.

Then make a complete bit-for-bit backup copy of the disk. Either boot the Mac in Recovery and create the backup from there, or take out the disk and use a seperate computer to create the backup.

After you have cloned the drive, you should perform recovery attempts on the cloned copy only!

Usually this is doing using specialized data recovery software. Both free and paid programs exists for multiple platforms - you can use for example a free Linux system to recovery files from an OS X system - it doesn't have to be a Mac program.

The best software to use depends on how much you want to spend, what kind of files you're looking to recover and how your disk was formatted before you erased it. Specially which type of partition table did you have, which type of file system did you have - and was the disk encrypted.

If you disk was encrypted with File Vault you'll probably have a very hard time ever getting anything recovered.